# how to random lines in txt with bash

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I have a txt file with some lines such as:

```
a
b
c
f
e
f
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

now I want to random lines and print it to another txt file for example:

```
f
6
e
1
and so on...
```

could any body help me?
I am new in bash scripting

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `shuf` (a part of GNU coreutils).

```
shuf inputfile > outfile
```

For example:

```
$ seq 10 | shuf 
7
5
8
3
9
4
10
1
6
2
```

Answer (score 2):

### There is an option for that

```
sort -R /your/file.txt
```

#### Expanation

> -R, --random-sort
>
> ```
>    sort by random hash of keys
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over the file, outputting each line with a certain probability (in this example, with roughly a 10% chance for each line:

```
while read line; do
    if (( RANDOM % 10 == 0 )); then
        echo "$line"
    fi
done < file.txt
```

(I say "roughly", because the value of `RANDOM` ranges between 0 and 32767. As such, there are slightly more values that will produce a remainder of 0-7 than there are that will produce  a remainder of 8 or 9 when divided by 10. Other probabilities are have similar problems; you can fine-tune the expression to be more precise, but I leave that as an exercise to the reader.)

Answer (score 1):

For less fortunates systems without GNU utils like BSD/OSX you can use this code:

```
for ((i=0; i<10; i++)); do
    n=$((RANDOM%10))
    sed $n'q;d' file
done
```